# Generally major network subnet mask is given for subnetting, how would you calculate it if it was not given?

Tags: networking, subnet

Generally you're given address with subnet mask to subnet. For example:

```
192.168.0.0/16
```

But say you're not given the address. You've to assume the address.

The hosts are given:

There are 5 departments:

- HR = 60
- Marketing = 60
- Coding = 60
- Testing = 60
- Control department = 5

So total hosts are 60*4+5=245

i.e you require 8 bits of host address(which is incorrect but keep on at it). You got 256 addresses.

But You should sacrifice initial and ending ip addresses. So total ip required becomes 245+5*2=255

I know that this is not correct because you can't allocate 62 ip addresses in subnetting, you can only do 64.

So is there any formula or sth so that I can find out the subnet mask from the number of hosts given directly?

I am pretty aware that I could choose major network subnet mask to be /1 and my job would be done. But that would make me look insane.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No. I was just thinking about a situation like this. Just playing around.

Comment: So if you had a known number of hosts, like 150, you would want to see if you can deduce the subnet mask from that? Might be possible. But I believe you would need to even use some of the IP addresses themselves to calculate what the mask might be.

Comment: IP address could be anything. Say 192.168.0.0.

Comment: [These excellent answers](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) tell you all you need to know about subnetting.

Comment: @Zac67 thanks a lot for your reply.. but they don't tell you about this imaginary question. they subnet based on the given ip+subnet mask. I have the answer but I was seeking some empirical way to do it. I will answer this myself to the best I can now.

Comment: With N being the number of nodes you need to accomodate, you need at minimum log2(N+2) bits, always rounded upwards. The maximum prefix length is 32 minus that number of bits. I'm sorry but I don't think that that really furthers your understanding.

Comment: @Zac67 What'd be the value of N here? If that's 60*4+5 then it doesn't yield right answer.

Comment: If you need N=60*4+5=245 hosts, log2(245+2) rounded up gives 8 bits. 32-8 = 24-bit prefix.

Comment: @Zac67 are you serious sir? I think you're joking. That is wrong answer. The whole confusion started for me because I thought the same as you are thinking here.

Comment: @systemzadmin Your question doesn't state whether "department" means IP subnet or if they should be all bunched together. That is nothing we can tell you. If you want a subnet each for 60 hosts, log2(60+2) => 6 host bits, 26-bit prefix. Pick what you need.

Comment: @Zac67. yes they're  "n" subnets. I thought it'd be obvious sorry for my mistake. PS I am asking major network mask. the answer is /26+/26+/26+/26+/29=/23

Answer (score 1):

> How to find major network subnet mask?

> There are 5 departments:
>
> - HR = 60
> - Marketing = 60
> - Coding = 60
> - Testing = 60
> - Control department = 5

---

Firstly make 5 equations-:

4*(2^x-2)=60*4-

ie 2^x -2 =60 --eqn 1)

2^y - 2=5 ---eqn 2)

Find the values of x and y.

## x=log_2 (60+2)

## y=log_2 (5+2)

Subnet mask required=z=32-x-y=23

Hence /23 is the major network subnet mask.

---

Another easier approach would be to think in terms of binary.

For 60 hosts can sit only in 64 ip address space. And 5 hosts in 8 ip address. So 64*4+8=264

log_2(264)=9

i.e 9 bits required for representing 264 addresses.

Thus subnet mask=32-9=23.

---

empirical answer for someone who likes to use math rather than calculation-:

Summation of (2^log_2(number of hosts per subnet+2)).

Summation ranges from first department to nth department.

but mind you to not use calculator as it will create wrong results.

first calculate log_2(no. of hosts per subnet+2)

then calculate its 2th power.

eg-: for 60, log_2(62)=6

then 2^6 =64

Similarly for another 4 subnets it becomes 64*4=256

Then for final subnet

log_2(7)=3

2^3=8

Thus 256+8=264 ip addresses are required.

log_2(264)=9

So 9 bits is required for these amount of hosts. i.e 32-9=23 as subnet mask.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Well, there's no point saying something is unclear unless you say what it is that you think is unclear., otherwise you are just trolling , you can keep saying something is unclear and expecting them to rewrite everything they said. Taking no time to explain yourself and  trying to get them to go mad, you have a good tactic there if that's your goal!.

Comment: @barlop please ask what you don't understand, it is pretty straightforward. It is a formula.

Comment: @systemzadmin Look  at who is commenting and what is said, I didn't say I didn't understand(maybe I do, maybe I don't, but I didn't say I didn't), Mr Community Bot did

Comment: @barlop everyone is hostile in internet, so i thought you were angry with me lol.

Comment: @systemzadmin Nope, and blame the "Community Bot"!

Comment: @barlop You can flag the Community Bot's comment as "No longer needed" if you want to.

Comment: @AndrewMorton well actually the reality is that he could clarify his answer and it isn't that clear, for example the question asked "Generally major network subnet mask is given for subnetting, how would you calculate it if it was not given?"   So one would expect an answer to end with giving a subnet mask. But his answer ends with "Thus 256+8=264 ip addresses are required.".   Also, my point is not that the communitybot's comment is "no longer needed". Check what I wrote in response to it.

Comment: @barlop Are you aware that [Community Bot](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) is not really a person?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  Yes. Are you aware that a person set that message up, thus pointing out a problem in that message still makes sense even if it's not a person? Also i'd be very interested to know how a bot determined that that answer wasn't clear. (And that last sentence is not making a statement about whether or not the answer is clear, so don't misunderstand that sentence) .

Comment: @barlop "i'd be very interested to know how a bot determined that that answer wasn't clear." - me too! Did I miss something on meta about it?